# Shortcut to erase the last character of the line in normal mode

Tags: vimrc

I'm searching for a command (let's say Ctrl+j) to add to my *.vimrc* to erase the last character of the line in normal mode, without changing position of the cursor. I'm beginner in this *.vimrc* language, sorry if it's too easy

Answer (score 2):

The normal mode commands would be something like `` ma$x`a ``. You can use any mark, and you could map this to a key if you like. I don’t entirely follow the use case, so I probably wouldn’t make a map for this. I might use `$xgi` if I wanted to jump to the last place I was inserting, or `$xg;` to jump to last modifications.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid setting marks and moving the cursor, and don't mind a little bit of Vim script, this should work:

```
:nmap <silent> <leader>d :call setline('.', getline('.')[:-2])<CR>
```

This depends on what your `mapleader` global variable is set to, but defaults to backslash, so the mapping will come out as `\d`.